# React multiple Bundle based on User Type

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a question i am working on an application using react relay graphql and using webpack as bundler.

App has three kind of UserType and all will have different dashboard, so i would like to have a common login for them and different bundle after successful login for respective dashboards, so that bundle size is reduced.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that, by configure your webpack:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        user1: path.join(__dirname, './client/app1.js'),
        user2: path.join(__dirname, './client/app2.js'),
        user3: path.join(__dirname, './client/app3.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './static/bundle/'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    ...
}
```

Name of bundles will be like user1.js, user2.js, user3.js

Comment: correct!! it requires one more things which is [Dynamic Routing](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md)  with react-router, otherwise we have to create multiple html files to load these bundles.

Comment: Glad to help with your problem)

Comment: I am still confused about entry points. Suppose I have one site `example.com` and two other pages `example.com/register` and `example.com/contact`. Now I want to get common files for `example.com` and load only register module code in `example.com/register` and contact module code in `example.com/contact`. The entry point is same, `example.com`. Does above solution work in this scenario?

Comment: @learner the entry point is a file name, not an url. In that case, you could define 3 entry points with commonChunkPlugin, which will extract common code to special file. As result you'll have 4 files: 1 - somecommonfile.js, 2 - bundle for main page `/` with only special code for main page, 3 - bundle for `/contact`, 4 - bundle for `register`. See here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#running-multiple-entry-points . Also, on the same docs page check dinamic module loading

Comment: Hi, do I need `Also, on the same docs page check dynamic module loading`? I want to load different bundle.js in different requests. How will I load `main.bundle.js` in main file case and `register.bundle.js` in case register url? Do I need multiple `index.html` files or single `index.html` file suffice?

Comment: Sorry, i cant help you in that case T__T In case when your index.html is just an empty template, I guess you'll need only include main.bundle.js in single index.html, and load other bundles dinamically depends on current route. In cases, when you'll need some specific html code in each html file, make few files and include necessary js bundles by hands)